# How can I align these two buttons in a custom way I want in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

How can I align these 2 buttons as displayed inside my Row in flutter, I tried using alignment and did not work probably because I have set mainAxisAlignment in my parent Column. The closest I got was by setting a flex for the items by wrapping my Custom widget around an Expanded. I wish to achieve the alignment of my 2 buttons(red button & gallery button) as in the below screenshot(the width of the screen is the width of the image), any help would be appreciated, thanks[image]

Comment: Please attach output image as well

Answer (score 0):

You can align the buttons within the Row by setting the mainAxisAlignment property to MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween. This will distribute the space evenly between the two buttons, aligning them to the left and right edges of the Row.

Alternatively, you can use the Expanded widget to give specific flex values to each button. For example, you can wrap the first button in an Expanded widget with a flex of 1 and the second button in an Expanded widget with a flex of 2. This will give the second button twice the amount of space as the first button.

You also can use crossAxisAlignment property in the child widgets like button to align them as you wish.